# Position text on left of content

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to position a text on left of some content (and move the content completely to the right?) Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="label">TO</div>
asdf<br/>
asdfasdf<br/>
asdfasdfasdf<br/>
```

Comment: Sorry, updated question.

Comment: HTML is illogical as it stands now. do not use `br` tags for margins

Answer (score 0):

There can be a solution for that,

```
<div class="label">TO</div>
<div class="text">
  <p>asdf</p>
  <p>asdfasdf</p>
  <p>asdfasdfasdf</p>
</div>
```

CSS would be

```
.label {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.text {
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}

.label, .text {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Now, this would be inline. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use absolute positioning on the element you want to stick to the left, and add padding to a containing element to give it space.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6KQ74/1/

```
p {
    padding-left: 3em;
    margin-left: 25px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 3;
}
    p .label {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 3em;
    }
```